# Winform Charting Histogram - Draw bar from start to end of bin

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I'm trying to create a proper histogram using the standard charting library in Winforms C#.  Currently my histogram looks as follows:

[image]

```
    var dataPointSeries = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series
    {
        Name = chartName,
        Color = Colors.blue,
        IsVisibleInLegend = false,
        ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column,
        MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.None,
        BorderWidth = 1,
        BorderColor = Color.White


    };
    for (int i = 0; i < data.hDataPoints.Count(); i++)
    {
        dataPointSeries.Points.AddXY(Charts.Functions.RoundValue(data.hDataPoints[i].fromBin), data.hDataPoints[i].probability);
    }

    chart.Series.Add(dataPointSeries);
    chart.Series[0]["PointWidth"] = "1";
```

The problem that I'm having is the bars are not displayed correctly.  For a histogram, the bar needs to start at the lower bin and end at the upper bin.  The chart control draws the bar in the middle of the upper or lower bin depending on which one you choose as the X data point.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you add 500 to your data points?

Comment: That's a good hack, but is there anything else that can be done?  Ideally the values on the axis should accompany the start and end of each bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you show is the automatic default display.

If you want to change it you need to code the correct values you want in the X-Axis.

Looks like you want this:

```
Axis ax = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;

ax.Minimum = -500;
ax.Maximum = 5500;
ax.Interval = 1000;
ax.IntervalOffset = -500;
```

[image]

Note that there will always be a small gap between the data points columns and half of it at the borders..

Also note that in a column chart each column (or, for multiseries charts, each group of data points,) is **always centered** at the x-axis value. Anything else would be misleading! The start/end ie the left/right **edges** of the column do not have any meaning!! `Columns` are only about their **center**!

If you would want anything else (and you don't if you are making a histogram) you would use an `Area` type chart.

If you find this counter-intutive get used to it by imagining adding another `Series` and the principle will become clear..

And if you decide you really need to associate a column to a value range then simply set its x-value to the middle of that range..:

```
        ax.Interval = 1000;
        ax.IntervalOffset = 0;
        ax.Minimum = 0;
        ax.Maximum = 6000;
         foreach (DataPoint dp in chart.Series[0].Points) dp.XValue += ax.Interval/2;
```

[image]

Again, note the gaps between the data points columns and half of it at the borders..

Answer (score 0):

TaW's answer about dividing the interval in half is correct, and will center the bar between two values ([as desired in historgrams which are used to represent bins, not discrete values](https://www.google.com/search?q=histogram&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS824US824&oq=histogram&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l2j0i131i433i512j0i512j0i131i433i512j69i60l2j69i61.1440j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)).

But to get a truly gapless histogram - if that is the look you are going for - add the following code:

```
chart.Series[0]["PointWidth"] = "1";
```

This should push the thickness of your bars to the full width of your range.